# Why isn't json_encode working?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm trying to encode some user input I'm fetching from a database and then insert it into a textarea on click. Here's my code for encoding the data, sending the user to the textarea anchor, and then triggering my function.

```
$quote = "[url]" . $quote . "[/url]";
$quote = htmlspecialchars($quote, ENT_QUOTES);
$quote = json_encode($quote, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "
<a href='#quickpost' value='quote' 
onClick=\"quote(" . $quote . ")\" name='quote'>Quote</a>
```

Here's the quote() function:

```
function quote(originalpost){
oFormObject = document.forms['id1'];
oFormObject.elements['post'].value = originalpost;
};
```

I'm getting this error in firebug when I click it: SyntaxError: syntax error
Line 1

I'm a complete novice when it comes to JavaScript, so I could be missing something totally obvious.
I've looked and tried a lot of different encoding options and things for this, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since JSON is native Javascript, you shouldn't quote it when declaring it in JS code or passing it around.

Try:

```
echo "
<a href='#quickpost' value='quote' 
onClick='quote($quote)' name='quote'>Quote</a>";
```

Then inside your function, you may need to stringify the JSON:

```
oFormObject.elements['post'].value = JSON.stringify(originalpost);
```

For sanity's sake, get a copy of the JSON produced by `json_encode` and run it through the [JSON lint utility](http://jsonlint.com) to make sure it is valid.

See if that works.  For browsers that don't have native stringify support, you can get the code for the function [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json.js).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make sure you are sending a string to the quote function. For what I see you might be sending `quote([url]...` while you should be sending `quote("[url]..."` (note the quotation chars)

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is from database, just output it as an array before you json encode it.

```
//array from database
$array = array();
//set the header
header("content-type:json/application");
return json_encode($array);
```

Then retrieve the encoded json as responseText.

```
var data = $.ajax({
  url:"",
  type:"json",
  cache:false,
  async:false
}).responseText;

var encodedData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Now you have a valid json object which is encodedData